# How to define and use a collection of ClassA inside a ClassB

Tags: vba, class, collections

Say I have a class called Person, with a Name and an Age properties, and another collection called Family, with properties like Income, Address, and a collection of Persons inside it.
I cannot find a full example on how to implement this concept.
Furthermore, as I am new to both collections and classes, I am not succeeding also in making a small subroutine to use these two functions.

Here is my best try, based on the limited resources available on the internet:

```
' Inside the class Module Person .........................
Public pName As String 
Public pAge As Integer
Public Property Get Name() As String
 Name = pName
End Property
Public Property Let Name(value As String)
 pName = value
End Property

' Inside the class Module Family .........................
' ... Income and address Properties are supposed 
' ... declared and will not be used in this trial
Private colPersons As New Collection

Function AddP(aName As String, anAge As integer)
'create a new person and add to collection
 Dim P As New Person
 P.Name = aName
 P.Age = anAge
 colPersons.Add R ' ERROR! Variable colPersons not Defined!
End Function

Property Get Count() As Long
'return the number of people
Count = colPersons.Count
End Property

Property Get Item(NameOrNumber As Variant) As Person
'return this particular person
Set Item = Person(NameOrNumber)
End Property
```

And now the Subroutine that tries to use the above:

```
Sub CreateCollectionOfPersonsInsideAFamily()
'create a new collection of people
Dim Family_A As New Family
'add 3 people to it
Family_A.AddP "Joe", 13
Family_A.AddP "Tina", 33
Family_A.AddP "Jean", 43
'list out the people
Dim i As Integer
For i = 1 To Family_A.Count
Debug.Print Family_A.Item(i).Name
Next i
End Sub
```

Naturally this is giving errors: Variable Not defined (see above comment)

Comment: why do you need to separate the classes ? is there a reason Person and family details are not in one Class ?

Comment: In fact in programs like Microsoft Projects we have like classes of Ressourses  and Tasks .  Both have lots of independent methods, properties etc and i cannot think of them as being one entity: the same ressource will be used for many tasks! My example of Person and Family is just to simplify the question.

Answer (score 2):

Sorry for the inconvenience... But the problem was that the line:

```
 Private colPersons As New Collection
```

should not be place after other properties have been declared (here not shown: Address and Income)

After placing this line in the declaration area at the top of its class, all the code has proved to be correct.

Comment: Good it was solved. Also note that when a member variable of a class is public, writing getters and setters makes no sense. Either make an attribute private and write `Get/Set` or make it public and no need for `Get/Set`. (I am talking about the attributes `pName` and `pAge` of the class `Person`).

Comment: Thanks for your input. This matter was little bit obscure for me and now it is more clear.